# Cocos2D-JS Windows App in fullscreen mode (Win32)

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, windows, cocos2d-x-js

I've been looking for a way to make my Cocos2D-JS app go into fullscreen mode, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on Cocos2D-JS (or Cocos2D-x-js as some seem to call it.)
This app is to be exported into a Windows Desktop platform (Win32), and so fullscreen mode should work there as well.

I checked the [Cocos2D-JS Online API](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.3/index.html) and found [cc.screen](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.3/symbols/cc.screen.html), which has a method called `requestFullScreen`, so I tried this:

```
cc.screen.requestFullScreen(document.documentElement, function() { cc.log('Requesting full screen...'); } );
```

However, this didn't work on either of the platforms I tested it on (web browser and win32). Since `document` does not exist when you export the app into win32, I then tried changing it for `cc._canvas`:

```
cc.screen.requestFullScreen(cc._canvas, function() { cc.log('Requesting full screen...'); } );
```

But this did not work either. Is there a way to make the app run in fullscreen mode?

PD: My apologies for any wrong tags I may have included to this question. I added the ones I thought were related to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the deployed cocos2d-js Win32 app run in fullscreen mode by modifying the `AppDelegate.cpp` file (located in `frameworks/runtime-src/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp`).

1. Inside the `AppDelegate.cpp` find method `applicationDidFinishLoading`
2. Within method `applicationDidFinishLoading`, look for this line:

   ```
   glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::createWithRect("MyAppName", Rect(0,0,900,640));
   ```
3. Call `createWithFullScreen` instead of `createWithRect`, and remove second argument (which sets the window size in window mode):

   ```
   glview = cocos2d::GLViewImpl::createWithFullScreen("MyAppName");
   ```
4. Compile/Deploy the app using `cocos compile -p win32`, `cocos deploy -p win32 -m debug`, or `cocos run -p win32`.

And that's it. :)